# CSS opacity defined at 0.3 but set at 0.30000001192092896

Tags: html, css

I have an `<input>` element for which I set `opacity: 0.3`. However, when I check the actual value I get 0.30000001192092896. See http://jsfiddle.net/85EPf/2/

Why do I get this discrepancy? If this is not a bug, how can I predict the discrepancy for other values?

Comment: *Even CSS* can't escape from floating point numbers?

Comment: I'm confused, your js fiddle has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Corrected! Thanks. (Didn't refresh the fiddle.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is yet another floating-point vs. decimal number rounding issue.  See ["What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

You don't really need to be concerned with the discrepency.  Just know that for floating point numbers, you can't express 0.3 exactly.  0.30000001192092896 is close enough.

Comment: "you don't really need to be concerned with the discrepancy" -> Actually, I found the discrepancy after going bug-hunting. This was the cause of a bug.

Comment: Is it because the code was relying on floating-point number comparisons?  That's not recommended.

Comment: Yes. What is a better approach?

Comment: Testing if the number is within tolerable range is one option.

Answer (score 1):

Floating point numbers represented in binary inside computers are not exact. Your value 0.30000001192092896 is the closest the computer can come to representing 0.3 in binary.

Comment: No it's not!  JS floats are accurate to roughly 15 digits.  Try `console.log (0.3000000000000001, ' | ', 0.3000000000000001 + 0.0000000000000001);`

Comment: @Brock Adams: That's the precision of *your* JS implementation, not the implementation of CSS in whatever browser the OP is using. Maybe it's only using single precision floats.

Comment: No, the [JS spec](http://www.ecmascript.org/docs.php) uses [IEEE 754, double-precision](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html).  Show me a browser that uses a different precision for its CSS.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, this is the result of the fact that [floating-point numbers are approximations in JS](http://steve.hollasch.net/cgindex/coding/ieeefloat.html) (and almost all other computer languages.)

If you want to test the opacity against a value, first decide how close is close enough.  For example, this tests to see if it's equal to 0.3, within 3 decimal places:

```
if (300 == Math.round (opactityVal * 1000) ) {
    //-- Do something here.
}
```

See, also, [*Minimizing the effect of accuracy problems*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Minimizing_the_effect_of_accuracy_problems).